# How to fix the "Cannot find or open the PDB file." in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

Every time I run a project in Visual Studio 2017, it loads all dll files. In the Debug output, I can see "*Symbols loaded*." after most of the dll files. But after the "*msvcp140d.dll*" and "*ig4icd32.dll*" files, it says "*Cannot find or open the PDB file.*"

How can I fix this?
Can someone help???

Comment: Why do you think you need to fix that?

Comment: Isn't it something wrong?

Comment: No it simply says that you don't have those PDB files. Unless you would like to debug the windows kernel binding or some other essential DLLs, you won't need them.

Comment: Does it do something if I don't have them? Like for graphics or making a game engine?

Comment: These files are debugging symbol databases, you don't need them as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this?

There is nothing to *"fix"*.

If you run your program in the Visual Studio debugger, it tries to probe for PDB files when DLLs are loaded at the startup of your program.

The message just states that the PDB files for some DLLs cannot be found and loaded.

Usually this will not be a problem since you don't need to debug `msvcp140d.dll` or similar system essentials.

Answer (score 0):

For pdb missing, Clean Solution and perform Rebuild Solution from project menu.
For 'msvcp140d.dll file not found' ,check your project settings, choose toolkit14, debug mode and linker setting for dynamic link. Try to install MS redistributable c++ for 2015 x86 and x64.